# Discover transformation required to align images of standardized documents

Tags: python, opencv

My question is not too far off from the ["Image Alignment (ECC) in OpenCV ( C++ / Python )" article](http://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/).

I also found [the following article](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/22/face-alignment-with-opencv-and-python/) about facial alignment to be very interesting, but WAY more complex than my problem.

[Wow! I can really go down the rabbit-hole.](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html)

My question is WAY more simple.

I have a scanned document that I have treated as a "template". In this template I have manually mapped the pixel regions that I require info from as:

```
area = (x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

such that `x1<x2`, `y1<y2`.

Now, these regions are, as is likely obvious, a bit too specific to my "template".

All other files that I want to extract data from are mostly shifted by some unknown amount such that their true area for my desired data is:

```
area = (x1 + ε1, y1 + ε2, x2 + ε1, y2 + ε2)
```

Where `ε1, ε2` are unknown in advance.

**But** the documents are otherwise HIGHLY similar outside of this shift.

I want to discover, ideally through opencv, what translation is required (for the time being ignoring euclidean) to "align" these images as to disover my `ε`, shift my area, and parse my data directly.

I have thought about using [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) to mine the text from the document and then parse from there, but there are check boxes that are either filled or empty

[image: filled check box] [image]

that contain  meaningful information for my problem.

The code I currently have for cropping the image is:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(img_path)
area = area_lookup['key']
cropped_img = img.crop(area)
cropped_img.show()
```

My two sample files are attached.

My two images are:

[image]

[image]

We can assume my first image is my "template".

As you can see, the two images are very "similar" but one is moved slightly (human error). There may be cases where the rotation is more extreme, or the image is shifted more.

I would like transform image 2 to be as aligned to image 1 as possible, and then parse data from it.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Always provide a couple of example images of your problem.

Comment: Ok I will post those later

Comment: "But the documents are otherwise HIGHLY similar outside of this shift." Definitely need to see the documents. The main problem that can happen with dense algorithms like ECC with documents is if one is blank except lines and the other has a ton of text on it, pixel for pixel they're actually not very similar matrices, so dense algorithms can have a hard time. Often the best approach is a feature based approach---maybe with your own defined features if there's good distinct markings on the pages.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I will upload two forms shortly.

Comment: @Zindarod i provided images

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I added the images

Comment: These *should* be an OK use of dense alignment as long as they're not too far off at the start (e.g. rotated 90 degrees or something). You might try to just align the tops or something where there is no user input and see if that will align the whole images well, that way there should be no actual difference between the two images aside from alignment.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds will this work as well when there is, let's say, an angle to the document < 30 deg? There may be cases of 180 deg rotation

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds also, may you post a proper answer that I may test and approve?

Comment: 30 degrees might still be much for dense alignment on a binary image. Dense alignment basically applies small transformations and asks "do I have more pixels in common with the original now?" -- if it does, it keeps going that direction. However you can imagine that when pixels are black and white and you do that, you might accumulate larger errors even going towards the right path. And this especially won't work 180 degrees. You might be able to get away with dense alignment with a pyramid resolution approach starting very small for ~20 degrees. Otherwise, feature based methods might be best.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Great. If my goal here is to create a new image with my sample being transformed to most closely match my original, could you provide some sample code in the solution? quite new to opencv

Comment: I might be able to tomorrow, but this requires a non-trivial amount of code.

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Also [this document](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~elm/Teaching/Docs/Image%20Align%20Szel.pdf) has everything you could possibly need to know about image alignment---just cruising through it a bit and skipping the mathy parts might help to digest the different methods and what they're good for. Szeliski is the author of one of the most popular [computer vision textbooks](http://szeliski.org/Book/) and that document is all the relevant parts of the book to image alignment.